# I get "terminated with status -1073741510" for my program, i tried to put conditions, but i still get it

Tags: c++, codeblocks

here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream f("v.in");
ofstream g("v.out");

int v[2000][2000];

int main()
{
    int s = 0;
    int imax, jmax, smax = 0;
    int n, m;
    int d;

    f >> m >> n;
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            f >> v[i][j];
        }
    }
        
    int i = 1, j = 1;
    for(i = 1; i + 2 <= n; i++)
    {
        for(d = 1; d < m && i + d * 2 <= n; d++)
        {
            int i2 = i + d * 2;
            s = 0;
            int ii1 = i;
            int ii2 = i2;
            
            for(j = 1; j <= d + 1; j++)
            {
                s = s + v[j][ii1++];
            }
            

            for(j=1;j<d+1;j++)
            {
                s = s + v[j][ii2--];
            }
            
            if(s > smax)
            {
                smax = s;
                imax = i;
                jmax = d + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    g << smax << ' ' << imax << ' ' << jmax;

    f.close();
    g.close();

    return 0;
}
```

the program must read the matrix in V starting from first line.
every time i get the **terminated with status -1073741510** and i cant find why.

```
1 ≤ m, n ≤ 1500
```

It has to show the max sum route showing, smax, and starting column and last row as in the example:

**v.in**

```
5 10
1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 -1 20 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 2
-3 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 20 -1
-2 -4 -5 -6 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10 -1
-20 -40 -4 -5 -6 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
```

**v.out**

```
22 3 2
```

I am begginer , please help

Comment: You get a *crash* and you need to use a *debugger* to catch the crash as it happens, to locate when and where in your code it happens. Using the debugger you can also examine variables and their values at the point of the crash, to see that they look valid.

Comment: Please attach a debugger and tells us which line actually causes the crash

Comment: i used the code blocks debugger to see where it happens but it was working good

Comment: There is so much unchecked indexing trickery that it would be very surprising if it were correct.

Comment: And *please* don't use competition/online judge sites to learn programming. Get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read, or even take classes. Such sites only teaches one thing: How to write bad code and acquire bad habits.

Comment: If the problem's maximum size is 2000 in each direction, you're indexing outside the arrays if either `m` or `n` is 2000.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ,i will try to find some good books,

Comment: @molbdnilo the maximum size is 1500,i know i put too much ,i wanted to avoid indexing outside the arrays

Comment: @VladPopescu Instead of `int v[2000][2000];` use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(m, std::vector<int>(n);` and then remember that indexing is zero-based in C++ so you can access `v[0][0]` to `v[m-1][n-1]` (inclusive). You can use the safe `at()` `vector` member function to get exceptions if you try to access the array out of bounds `v.at(m-1).at(n-1)` which can help when debugging.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, i will try to do it

Comment: Oups, it should have been: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(m, std::vector<int>(n));` - I missed a parenthesis.

Comment: On windows `-1073741510` is `0xC000013A` which is `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55)

Comment: Even the first for loop starts indexing @ 1 for some reason. It should be `(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)` and not `(int i = 1; i <= m; ++i)`. This doesn't create problems right now since the matrix is over-sized, but this is a huge code smell.